# Need to create session object and along with session object I want to send my own NSDictonary object in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, session, nsdictionary

I have a situation to 'Login' in window based mac application , for that login I am going to 'LoginValidation' file. This is working fine and it is giving proper response for opening a what I needed.

But the problem is I need to send my own dictionary object(consists of login information) to the next page(what I am opening newly). If I try to import 'LoginValidation' or 'Login' page in here its not allowing me for creating of complete circle loop.

For this reason I am thinking only by using session I can send my object from one page to another page.
Can any one please help me how to come out with solution....
Thank u in advance...

Comment: do u mean that u need to send ur own dictionary from view 1 to view 2 right?